# forking an android project

Tags: android, project, duplicates, fork

I have a very special problem. Base on my previous question, you can tell that I was working on a live wallpaper. It's now available on the market (under the name Weird Voronoi).

But now, I want to create a "pro" version of this, with more feature and so on. But I'm not sure of the right approach for this. If I try to start a second project and use the current one as a "library" to reuse some part of it, I might have to do a lot of changes in the original project. Plus I will have to redo (at least I think) all the settings and ending up with twice the material to maintain after that. Need to do a second manifest and adjust it to fit my new needs.

What should I do ? Copy completely the project into another one and start from that point ? I really don't know what would be the best approach. I would like to reuse the maximum of code that I can and not duplicate the files. But if the fastest way is to duplicate, I will do it.

Thanks

W

Comment: The best way is your first suggestion. Put most of it in a library project so only the manifest is duplicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this tutorial on having full and lite versions of an Android project off the same code base: http://blog.donnfelker.com/2010/08/05/howto-android-full-and-lite-versions/